# Tableau Stacked Bar Charts Duplicates

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, stacked

I am new to using Tableau and I would like to create a stacked bar chart that contains multiple instances of the same data type. For instance, data of the form:

Offset:    0   10   20  30  40
Character: A   A    B   A   C

would yield a stacked bar chart with the color for 'A' from 0 to 20, 'B' for 20 to 30, 'A' for 30 through 40, and 'C' from 40 to some default terminating value.

Is this sort of thing possible with Tableau? Sorry if the answer to this is already well-documented, but I haven't been able to find it in any tutorials so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau will group the 'A's together unless you give them a unique id. If you give them a unique id, you can put the unique id in the detail field then put the Character in the Label (and perhaps Color) field.

This should give the effect you desire. You can drag the elements in a legend to reorder them.